# How to translate "hymn sing" to Spanish referring to a church event?

Tags: modismos, terminología, música, religión

A church I'm working with has an event called a "hymn sing." (A leader takes requests and the group sings random hymns from a specified hymnal.)

I need to translate "hymn sing" to Spanish, but can't find a translation that suits me -- "himno cantar" was one suggestion, "reunión de cantar himnos" was another.

I'm hoping that this community can help. Thanks.

Comment: 'Canto de himnos' seria mi primera opcion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hymn* is easy and unambiguous. On the other hand, "sing" has many meanings.

I think the meaning you want is **"the abstract act and effect of singing"**, therefore you should use the Spanish word **"canto"**. Maybe **"canto de himnos"**

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracías, Amigo! Estaba pensando con toda fuerza - y sabía que sería algo muy fácil - pero no me aguanté saber la traducción.